# Selenium testing but every time occurs error StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, cucumber, gherkin

I write test scripts in Java 8, using libraries:

- selenium-java ver 3.8.1,
- cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, cucumber-core cucumber-java8, cucumber-picocontainer ver 1.2.5
- gherkin ver 2.12.2

I used Page Object Pattern with PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
and annotation @FindBy()
In code I used WebDriverWait, FluentWait on elements but without any profits.
Someone has any idea how to resolve this error?:

```
      org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
    (Session info: headless chrome=60.0.3112.101)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Linux 4.4.0-77-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
  Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
  For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
  Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'
  System info: host: 'officeDevelopmentServer', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.4.0-77-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
  Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
  Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 60.0.3112.101, webStorageEnabled: true}
```

Comment: Just for trial/error sake, could you put in a thread.sleep in between? Just to check if its a timing issue?

Comment: with thread.sleep working properly